Dovecot local user lookup and login fails. Where is my configuration incorrect?
I'm running dovecot 2.3.21 with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I'm trying to configure the server to work with both virtual and local users. Virtual users are working fine, but I'm having trouble authenticating a local user when trying to retrieve email using a client like Roundcube. I can authenticate the local user (which exists in /etc/passwd and has a valid home directory) using doveadm:
$ sudo doveadm auth login test <passwd>
passdb: test auth succeeded
extra fields:
  user=test

userdb extra fields:
  test
  system_groups_user=test
  uid=5002
  gid=5002
  home=/home/test
  auth_mech=PLAIN
$

Here's the log produced when trying to login using Roundcube:
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=178248)
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1       CRAM-MD5        service=imap    secured session=W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB        lip=127.0.0.1       rip=127.0.0.1   lport=143       rport=55570
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT    1       PDM1ODYyOTExNDk5NjY2NjUuMTczMzA4NDYxMEBtYXJhdWRlcj4=
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: client in: CONT    1       ZG1hcmMtcnVhQHByb2N1cmF0dXMubmV0IDYyZjRmNmQzY2RjOGY3MTA4ZDliMDMyMDI2YTYxYmNm (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: pam(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): Performing passdb lookup
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: pam(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): passdb doesn't support credential lookups
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: pam(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): Finished passdb lookup
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: passwd-file(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): Performing passdb lookup
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: passwd-file(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): lookup: user=test@myserver.net file=/etc/dovecot/passwd
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Info: passwd-file(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): unknown user
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: passwd-file(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): Finished passdb lookup
Dec 01 15:23:30 auth: Debug: auth(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>): Auth request finished
Dec 01 15:23:32 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL    1       user=test@myserver.net
Dec 01 15:23:32 imap-login: Info: Disconnected: Connection closed (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=<test@myserver.net>, method=CRAM-MD5, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<W92MNDsoEtl/AAAB>

Note the "passdb doesn't support credential lookups" and "unknown user" messages. Here's what I have configured in auth-system.conf.ext:
passdb {
  driver = pam
  args = session=yes failure_show_msg=yes dovecot
}

userdb {
  driver = passwd
}

What am I missing here?

PAM indeed doesn't support lookups. The only thing it supports is interactive checking, i.e. it cannot be queried for the password hash but can only be given a password and will answer whether that's valid or not.
But your RoundCube is trying to use CRAM-MD5, which doesn't work that way – it is a challenge-response mechanism (very similar to NTLM in concept) where the client doesn't send the server an actual password which it could verify; instead the mechanism requires Dovecot to pull out the password hash in order to verify the response against it, which PAM cannot do. (On top of that, by its nature CRAM-MD5 requires the stored hash to be in a very specific format; your /etc/shadow hashes wouldn't work either way.)
Set your Dovecot auth_mechanisms to only offer PLAIN and not CRAM:
auth_mechanisms = plain


Thanks, making that change has made progress, but now I'm getting a password mismatch error - and the password used is EXACTLY the same password as set for the local user:
```Dec 01 16:29:29 auth-worker(185445): Info: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=185444,uid=0): auth-worker<8>: pam(test@myserver.net,127.0.0.1,<cCFwIDwo5LJ/AAAB>): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (Password mismatch?) (given password: hidden)````
